# Shell script to copy a file from one location to another

Tags: shell

I have written a Unix command to copy a file from one location to other and saved it with script.sh in my E:\ drive in Windows10. However,while executing through the command prompt by  going to the path where this script is located,it throws pop up windows saying "how do you want to open this file?".Command in the script as below:

cd E:/source
for f in *.txt
do 
   cp -v "$f" E:/Destination/"${f%.txt}"$(date +%m%d%y).txt
done

Please help to fix this error.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you added the #!/bin/bash to the top of the script? cygwin I presume?

Comment: No i missed that part.

Comment: Even after adding #!/bin/bash on the top of the script i am getting pop up message.

Comment: made the script executable with 'chmod +x script.sh' ?

Comment: Does it contain DOS line ending? What did you "write" it in? You must use an editor that can properly save the file with Unix Line Endings (`'\n'`) **not** (`"\r\n"`).

Comment: You say *through the command prompt*. Which shell is running your command prompt? Also, please edit your posting so that your script is formatted properly.